# How to prove that a relation property holds for a transitive closure of this relation?

Tags: graph-theory, isabelle, theorem-proving

I defined the following relation property:

```
definition rel_limited_under :: "('a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a set ⇒ bool" where
  "rel_limited_under R A = 
   (∀x y z :: 'a. R x y ⟶ R y z ⟶ x ∈ A ⟶ z ∈ A ⟶ y ∈ A)"
```

A relation `R` is limited under a set `A` iff any two elements `x` and `z` from this set can be related only through an element `y` belonging to this set. In other words elements from set `A` can't be related through an element not belonging to this set.

Do you know a common name of this property? I think it's something from graph theory.

Could you suggest how to prove that the property holds for transitive closure of a relation?

```
lemma rel_tcl_limited_under:
  fixes R :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
    and A :: "'a set"
  assumes as_R: "rel_limited_under R A"
  shows "rel_limited_under R⇧+⇧+ A"
```

Comment: **Path** is closest related, but you certainly already know that. The nodes (edges) of every _path_ between `x` and `z` is contained in `A`. Vertices and edges of the paths appartain to the graph. Either x is an ancestor of z or vice versa.

Comment: I mean a common name of this subgraph `A`. If one will collapse the set `A` into a single node, then there will not be any pathes going from `A` to `A` in the graph. I thought such subgraph has some special name.

Comment: Something like connected component or clique. But it seems that this kind of subgraphs is too specific to have a special name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you that you cannot prove the property `rel_tcl_limited_under` in Isabelle, since it just does not hold. As a counterexample, consider `A = {0}` and `R = {(0,1), (1,2), (2,0)}`. Then `rel_limited_under R A` is trivially satisfied, since there are no `x, y, z` such that `R x y /\ R y z /\ x ∈ A /\ z ∈ A`. But `rel_limited_under (R^+) A` does not hold: choose `x = 0, y = 1, z = 0`.

Comment: Thanks! I redefined the property as `∀x y z. R⇧+⇧+ x y ⟶ R y z ⟶ x ∈ A ⟶ z ∈ A ⟶ y ∈ A`. And this property is just fine for my theory. I don't need to prove the lemma from question.

Comment: With this refinement it should be easy to use induction on the transitive closure. Start from `x in A`, `R^+ x y`, `z in A` and `R^+ y z`. Then by induction on `R^+ y z` one sees that all elements between `y` and `z` must be in `A`.